# Why do the directories /home, /usr, /var, etc. all have the same inode number (2)?

Tags: linux, filesystems, inode

I find that under my root directory, there are some directories that have the same inode number:

```
$ ls -aid */ .*/

2 home/ 2 tmp/ 2 usr/ 2 var/ 2 ./ 2 ../ 1 sys/ 1 proc/
```

I only know that the directories' names are kept in the parent directory, and their data is kept in the inode of the directories themselves.

I'm confused here.

This is what I think when I trace the pathname /home/user1.

- First I get into the inode 2 which is the root directory which contains the directory lists.
- Then I find the name home paired with inode 2.
- So I go back to the disk to find inode 2?
- And I get the name user1 here?

Comment: See also: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Inodes.html

Answer (score 45, accepted):

They're on different devices.

If we look at the output of `stat`, we can also see the device the file is on:

```
# stat / | grep Inode
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 2           Links: 24
# stat /opt | grep Inode
Device: 803h/2051d      Inode: 2           Links: 5
```

So those two are on separate devices/filesystems. Inode numbers are only unique within a filesystem so there is nothing unusual here. On ext2/3/4 inode 2 [is also always the root directory](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Special_inodes), so we know they are the roots of their respective filesystems.

The combination of device number + inode is likely to be unique over the whole system. (There are filesystems that don't have inodes in the traditional sense, but I think they still have to fake some sort of a unique identifier in their place anyway.)

The device numbers there appear to be the same as those shown on the device nodes, so `/dev/sda1` holds the filesystem where `/` is on:

```
# ls -l /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 1 Sep 21 10:45 /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Thank you,  now I get stat, useful for me, I'll learn to use it.

Comment: For the record, all filesystems have some equivalent, even when they dynamically allocate inodes.  For example, on BTRFS (which does dynamic inode allocation, in contrast to ext2/3/4's static inode tables), the particular inode value that is used like this is 256 (because everything lower is reserved for special entries in the metadata trees).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn, some filesystems such as FAT or ISO9660 don't have inodes in any meaningful sense of the word.  The filesystem driver does some slight-of-hand to make it look to the rest of the system that they do.

Comment: @Mark: The only "meaningful sense of the word" per the standard that defines it is "file serial number [unique within the device]". Insisting on thinking of inodes as a particular on-disk data structure is about as backwards as thinking of ttys as mechanical teletypes.

Comment: @R.., I suppose by that definition the FAT filesystem has inodes, but the "file serial number" for a given file on a FAT filesystem isn't stable across mounts, or even over time on a single mount: if memory pressure causes a synthesized inode structure to be evicted from the cache, the file gets a new number the next time something requests its inode data.

Comment: @R.., so, what is that unique file serial number on FAT? The number of its directory entry (where pretty much all the data contained in a Unixy inode sit, along with the file name)? The number of its first data block (i.e. the pointer to the FAT chain also stored in the directory entry)? Something else?

Comment: @ilkkachu: It's determined by the OS implementation that's providing a FAT-backed filesystem, not by the on-disk format. If I were implementing it I'd probably just use the cluster number of the start of the file. Synthesizing them in a way that they're lost and subject to change without remounting is buggy and non-conforming, and a waste of complexity since you can just use something simple and invariant like the cluster number.

Comment: @R.., well it has to be based on something that's on-disk, otherwise it's hard to make nonvolatile. I suppose the number of the first cluster works, if you're willing to force all files to occupy at least one (including zero-length files). I also thought the idea of the inode number is partly to be able to find the file information without a name, and you can't do that on FAT with just the cluster number. But then I'm not sure that needs to have anything to do with the `st_ino` that's visible to userland.

Comment: @R.., as for conforming... I'm pretty sure FAT doesn't support a bunch of other features found in Unix standards either.

Answer (score 26):

The inode number of any given file is unique to the filesystem, but not necessarily unique to all filesystems mounted on a given host. When you have multiple filesystems, you will see duplicate inode numbers between filesystems, this is normal.