# Why do /dev, /run, /proc, /sys, ... have inode 1 (and not 2)?

Tags: inode

I was reading [the EXT4 doc](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Special_inodes) about special inodes. It states that a FS root directory has inode #2. There are many posts in which people ask why directories like `/dev`, `/proc`, `/run`, `/sys`, and so on, have also inode #2, [the answer usually being](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073802/what-are-directories-if-everything-on-linux-is-a-file) :

> they're virtual filesystems, so since they are root folders for their filesystem, they also have inode 2

But on my system (Debian 11, EXT4), all those directories have inode #1 :

```
$ stat /sys | grep Inode
Device: 14h/20d Inode: 1           Links: 13

$ stat /proc | grep Inode
Device: 15h/21d Inode: 1           Links: 341

$ stat /run | grep Inode
Device: 17h/23d Inode: 1           Links: 33

$ stat /dev | grep Inode
Device: 5h/5d   Inode: 1           Links: 22
```

[EXT4's doc](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Special_inodes) states that Inode #1 is for `List of defective blocks.`

What's going on there ? Why don't those directories have inode #2, like they apparently have with other people ?

Comment: Only disk filesystems are ext4. /proc /sys are (always) virtual filesystems mocked-up by the kernel and cannot have bad blocks. /dev is usually either virtual or RAM-based, and /run is a usually RAM-based (tmpfs). Check `mount | grep /blah`.

Comment: I know they are virtual file systems. But it seems in most peoples' setup those dirs have inode #2, not #1 (see for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607640/why-inode-numbers-of-dev-and-run-are-same-as-that-of, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073802/what-are-directories-if-everything-on-linux-is-a-file, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408192/why-do-the-directories-home-usr-var-etc-all-have-the-same-inode-number-2, ...). Why do I have #1 ?

Comment: @ChennyStar the posts you link to are over 3, 5 and 6 years respectively. I have an Ubuntu 18.04 system and an Ubuntu 20.04 system (both on kernel 5.4, over 3 years old now) which has inode 1 for `/proc` and `/sys`, and 2 for `/dev` and `run`. So things were not that constant even back then. And of course, any talk of ext4 is completely irrelevant to the discussion since none of these are ext4 filesystems.

Comment: Anyway the title is misleading: these are not ext4. Title and tag should be amended.

Comment: @muru - ok thanks I get it now

Comment: Note that the quote in that AskUbuntu answer refers to [an U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408192/why-do-the-directories-home-usr-var-etc-all-have-the-same-inode-number-2) where it is clearly seen that the virtual filesystems do _not_ necessarily have inode 2.

Comment: @Kusalananda - yes indeed, the AskUbuntu answer is wrong on that particular point (stating that virtual filesystems'root all have inode 2).

Comment: Anyway, in case someone else is as confused as I was, some useful links that helped me understand : https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/swmqeg/inode_1/, https://superuser.com/questions/1454561/why-proc-and-sys-have-inode-1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099121/why-do-inode-numbers-start-from-1-and-not-0/2109363#2109363.

Comment: I suggested an edit to the AskUbuntu answer, hopefully clarifying that text. I don't have an account on that site, so we'll see if they accept my anonymous edit suggestion.

Comment: @Kusalananda - I'm not familiar with how "edit suggestions" work, but note that the author of the post hasn't been seen in 2 years (https://askubuntu.com/users/295286/sergiy-kolodyazhnyy)

Comment: @ChennyStar That's a minor issue as edits go into the edit review queue and may be processed by anyone with access to that queue.

Comment: @Kusalananda - ok thanks, good to know